# How to use Error handling / Exception Handling in Java?

Tags: java

So I'm trying to implement error catcher in my program but I'm not 100% sure on how they actually work, I have look some tutorials on YouTube but the way they explain it to me was not 100% clear, So what I'm actually trying to do here is trying to have at the end of the code something that if you insert a letter or number that he cannot recognise he's not going to give us an error but he's going to give us a message that tells us what went wrong.

What I tried to make was a much easier version with if statements, but I think that that is not exactly a good fit for this code because I would have to rewrite everything with if statements and I'm not sure how actually work.

**Code that I think can work**

[It was not letting me put the code here :C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQkdS.png)

**Code That I'm trying to implement Error handling**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
                Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Insert number of students: ");
                String student = sc.nextLine();
                int studenti = Integer.parseInt(student);
                 int[] array = new int[studenti];
                for (int i = 0; i<studenti;i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Insert a score in percentage: ");
                    String score = sc.nextLine();
                    
                    array[i]= Integer.parseInt(score);
                    
                }
                
                System.out.println("\nPercentages are: ");
                int sum = 0; // Added a variable for sum
                for (int i = 0; i < studenti; i++) {
                  System.out.println((array[i]) + "%");
                  sum += array[i]; // maintaining sum
                }
                int average = sum / array.length; // calculating the average
                System.out.println("\nThe Average Score is: " + average + "%");
```

}

Comment: "trying to have at the end ... tells us what went wrong" I'm having difficulty understanding what you mean by that. Mostly, because there *is* no end to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a try/catch block.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Insert number of students: ");
                String student = sc.nextLine();
          try{   
                int studenti = Integer.parseInt(student);
                 int[] array = new int[studenti];
                for (int i = 0; i<studenti;i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Insert a score in percentage: ");
                    String score = sc.nextLine();
                    
                    array[i]= Integer.parseInt(score);
                    
                }
                
                System.out.println("\nPercentages are: ");
                int sum = 0; // Added a variable for sum
                for (int i = 0; i < studenti; i++) {
                  System.out.println((array[i]) + "%");
                  sum += array[i]; // maintaining sum
                }
                int average = sum / array.length; // calculating the average
                System.out.println("\nThe Average Score is: " + average + "%");
    }catch(Exception ex){
     System.out.println("Error, details: " + ex.Message());
}
```

There are many 'Exception' you can use, numberFormatException for example.

Answer (score 0):

Error handling is not so complicated, really. It's about knowing what kind of exception is thrown in the scope of the `try` statement. This information is usually available by your IDE when you put the cursor over the method you are using.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        System.out.println("Insert number of students: ");
        int student = sc.nextInt(); // note Im using a method specific for int, instead of parsing
        int[] array = new int[student];
        for (int i = 0; i < student; i++) {
            System.out.println("Insert a score in percentage: ");
            String score = sc.nextLine();
            array[i]= Integer.parseInt(score);
        }
        System.out.println("\nPercentages are: ");
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < student; i++) {
            System.out.println((array[i]) + "%");
            sum += array[i];
        }
        int average = sum / student; // student == array.length
        System.out.println("\nThe Average Score is: " + average + "%");
    } catch (InputMismatchException | NumberFormatException exception) {  
        // This will catch errors due wrong input (ie user entered a letter 
        // instead of a digit) and execute the code within this block.
        // Another possible Exception thrown is IllegalStateException.
        System.err.println("There was an error. Details:");
        exception.printStackTrace(System.err); // remove if you don't want to see the error trace
    } finally { // this will get executed whether your code had errors or not
        sc.close(); // dont forget to close your scanner
    }
}
```

If your IDE doesn't show you information about a method, it might not be documented or you don't have said documentation imported. For that case, just google a bit and you'll find the exceptions. For example, [this link show you information about Scanner.nextInt()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanner-nextint-method-in-java-with-examples/) and [this about Integer.parseInt()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-integer-parseint-method).

Answer (score 0):

The broken part in the code is divide by zero. To handle the exception

```
 try {
        int average = sum / array.length; // throw Exception
    }
    catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        System.out.println(
            "Divided by zero operation cannot possible");
    }
```